# Why is 着 used for both "to wear" [着]{き}る and "to arrive" [着]{つ}く?

Tags: kanji

The usual situation with multiple *kun* readings for a kanji is that they are closely related in meaning (like [上]{あ}がる, [上]{のぼ}る). But with [着]{き}る and [着]{つ}く I fail to see any semantic connection. Why is the same character used? Did one of the meanings formerly use another character that became the same by simplification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etymology aside, I see a semantic connection between the two verbs, in that 着る and 着く both have a meaning of 'attachment', with 着く having at least [some overlap](http://bimyo-kotoba.com/back051104.htm) with 付く.  着物 is something attached to your body.  It is a bit unintuitive but you can make the leap of arriving at a place as entering into it and becoming spatially attached to it as in　駅に着く.

I didn't find an 'official' source, but I found [one QA site answer](http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2009/0728/254087.htm) that supposes a similar thing:

１）身につける＝着る

２）行きつく＝到着

Also see the link for lots of different opinions.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in Chinese 着 does not mean "arrive" (but can mean "wear"). In Chinese, "arrive" is 到, which we know from 到着【とうちゃく】, of course. Why the meaning of "arrive" was assigned a 訓読み of 着, rather than an alternative reading for 到 is not clear, unless one gives an explanation that links the meanings of "arrive" and "attach" (like in this answer).

Comment: 到 is pretty much a Modern Chinese/Mandarin word. I don't recall any Classical work using it and it would feel very out of place. Based on my Chinese intuition I think the 着 has the core meaning of something flat falling down and landing on something and staying there touching a surface firmly. In Modern Chinese it has very little meaning by itself but shows up in compounds relating to firmness, planes landing, etc.