# Why both 弟 and 第 kanji have the same 音読み?

Tags: etymology

I am trying to understand why both 弟 and 第 kanji have the same 音読み pronunciation ダイ/テイ? The common element [弔](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%94) is a variant of [吊](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%8A#Chinese) - is its Chinese pronunciation close to ダイ/テイ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have the same *on'yomi* because「弟」and「第」were originally the same character, representing a word to do with *sequence* or *order*; *younger brother* is an extension of this meaning (via *ordering of male siblings*).「第」was created from「弟」by corrupting「丷」to「⺮」. In Mandarin Chinese, the two characters also sound identical ([**dì**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Zh-d%C3%AC.ogg)), and bears distant similarity to **ダイ/テイ**.

Despite「弔」looking like it shows up in「弟」and「第」, they are unrelated.

> For reference,「弔」depicts a person「人」wielding a bird-capturing device; the device is comprised of an arrow attached to a very long rope, and is the original character of「/繳」.
>
> ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1870
> [合集27738](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27738&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>

---

「弟」is comprised of a handle of a pole-arm weapon「必」and a depiction of binding rope inscribed in an「Ｓ」shape. It originally represented an ordered bundle of weapon handles, extended to mean *order*, then *ordered male siblings* > *younger brother*.

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8818</kbd>
　<kbd>秦
簡
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)ㆍ[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)2</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

> 「必」is not related to「心」!「必」was originally「戈」([*dagger-axe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe)) with the blade part omitted, leaving the handle part. The modern meaning *certain* is a phonetic loan.
>
> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3069「必」
> [合集14034](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=14034&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)622「戈」
> [合集33208](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33208&jgwfl=)</kbd>
>
> The handle part of the weapon is now written as「柲」. Later on, decorative marks were added to the character, leading to the modern form.
>
> ## <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 南宮乎鐘
> [集成181](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=181&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> 睡ㆍ[秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)98</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> Compare「心」, which depicts a heart with the heart chambers becoming exaggerated, then later heavily abbreviated.
>
> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3510
> [合集6](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 史墻盤
> [集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> 簡
> [image]
> [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference).218</kbd>
> 　
> <kbd>篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>[魏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Wei)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 上尊號奏</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

The「丷」part of「弟」was an eventual detachment from the main body of the handle. In some variants,「丷」was corrupted into「艹」, [then again corrupted into「⺮」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42827/what-is-the-character-etymology-of-%E7%9D%80?noredirect=1&lq=1), leading on to the modern form of「第」, which preserves the meaning *order* or *sequence* and is not used for the meaning *younger brother*.

## <kbd>秦
簡
[image]
睡ㆍ日甲2</kbd>
　<kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)

[image]
御食官鼎</kbd>
　<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
隸
[image]
魯峻碑</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

## References:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Answer (score 6):

So [弟](http://jigen.net/kanji/24351) is actually a 象形{しょうけい} (pictograph) and it is pronounced ダイ (among others of course).

On the other hand [第](http://jigen.net/kanji/31532) is a 形声{けいせい} (kanji in which one element suggests the meaning and one the sound) and from the link you can see that the pronunciation comes just from 弟. So I guess you should really look at 弟 as the phonetic part rather than 弔.